# How to get require output using order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

Could you help me, i am expecting output is,

```
select * from table order by value
```

**Output:**

```
Value
E1
E2
O
R
```

**Required Output:**

```
R
E1
E2
O
```

Comment: why this scenario???...can you explain this

Comment: I want to display Emp ID is deparnment wise.R,E1,E2 & O are department values. R department will come 1st, E1 comes to 2nd position,like that.,

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM yourTable
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN VALUE = 'R' Then 1 Else 0 End,Value ASC
```

If you are using `UNION` then try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT *
    FROM table2
) T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN VALUE = 'R' Then 1 Else 0 End,Value ASC
```

Comment: Thank u very much., it's working fine, if i using union all operator for merging two table, its showing error. Error line below ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Answer (score 0):

a bit of a hack but if that's what you want...

```
order by 
case when value='r' then 1
    when value='e1' then 2
    when value='e2' then 3
    when value='o' then 4 end
```

Comment: Thank u very much., it's working fine, if i using union all operator for merging two table, its showing error. Error line below ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN value = 'R'     THEN 0
            WHEN value LIKE 'E%' THEN 1
            WHEN value = 'O'     THEN 2 
          END, LEN(value), value
```

Output:

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|     R |
|    E1 |
|    E2 |
|     O |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e91b6/4)** demo

---

> *...if i using union all operator for merging two table, its showing error...*

With `UNION` you can do

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM table1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT *
    FROM table2
) q
 ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN value = 'R'     THEN 0
            WHEN value LIKE 'E%' THEN 1
            WHEN value = 'O'     THEN 2 
          END, LEN(value), value
```

Comment: Thank u very much., it's working fine, if i using union all operator for merging two table, its showing error. 

Error line below

ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.